# Reusing method from another class without inheritance or delegation in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to use a method from another class.
Neither inheritance nor delegation is a good choice (to my understanding) because the existing class is too complicated to override and too expensive to instanciate.
Note that modifying the existing class is not allowed (legacy project, you know).

I came up with a way:

```py
class Old:
    def a(self):
        print('Old.a')

class Mine:
    b = Old.a
```

and it shows

```py
>>> Mine().b()
Old.a
>>> Mine().b
<bound method Old.a of <__main__.Mine object at 0x...>>
```

It seems fine.
And I tried with some more complicated cases including property modification (like `self.foo = 'bar'`), everything seems okay.

My question:
What is actually happening when I define methods like that?
Will that safely do the trick for my need mentioned above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Explanation

What's happening is that you are defining a callable class property of class `Mine` called `b`. However, this works:

```py
m = Mine()
m.b()
```

But this won't:

```py
Mine.b()
```

### Why doesn't the second way work?

When you call a function of a class, python expects the first argument to be the actual object upon which the function was called. When you do this, the `self` argument is automatically passed into the function behind the scenes. Since we called `Mine.b()` without an instantiated instance of any object, no `self` was passed into `b()`.

### Will this "do the trick"?

As for whether this will do the trick, that depends.

As long as `Mine` can behave the same way as `Old`, python won't complain. This is because the python interpreter does not care about the "type" of `self`. As long as it walks like a duck and quacks like a duck, it's a duck (see [duck typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing)). However, can you guarantee this? What if someone goes and changes the implementation of `Old.a`. Most of the time, as a client of another system we have no say when the private implementation of functions change.

A simpler solution might be to pull out the functionality you are missing into a separate module. Yes, there is some code duplication but at least you can be confident the code won't change from under you.

Ultimately, if you can guarantee the behavior of `Old` and `Mine` will be similar enough for the purposes of `Old.a`, python really shouldn't care.

Comment: Thanks for your clear explanation! `Mine.b()` is indeed missed in my tests because it is not an expected use case of `b`. Well, I will, at last, take your advice to copy-paste those codes to a new module. The reason that I have this question is the ugly implementation of the old class, then why should I care about that? lol

Comment: Glad to hear the answer helped! Since it did, please consider accepting the answer.